# Because of MKMapView app get crashed on pushViewController and PopviewController frequently?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am new in iOS development,

I need a `MKMapView` with custom pin annotation and custom callout bubble,I already achieved this,
I need another situation when button clicked the mapview get refreshed with new points.
For this purpose I tried to remove all annotation and add new annotation but this is not working it change my custom pin Images so I solved this problem in following manner,

First I removed old map view Using removeFromSuperView
and added new `MKMapView` programmatically using addsubview and add annotation on it.

BUT NOW PROBLEM IS,
my app get crashes when I push and pop view controller frequently

What I do for solve this problem ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove your entire map view just to clear the annotations off. I think you need to go back to how you remove the annotations and add new ones. Can you show us some code and maybe we'll get to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set mapView.delegate to nil in viewWillDisappear and set mapView.delegate to self in viewWillAppear.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried this but I its not working... I get 'received memory warning' ?